# How to dynamically change a form in django based on user input (before submission)

Tags: python, html, django, forms, dynamic

I'm doing a web page that contains a form that must be changed dynamically based on the previous user inputs (before it's submitted). For example, if a name ends up with the string `S.L`, it needs to automatically span the rest of the fields to introduce the company data, if not it must submit the form with the default values or with any value at all.

The form inherits from a model and everything is rendered as a crispy form.

In the views.py I have:

```
@login_required
def form_home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        Inputs = InputsForm(request.POST)

        if Inputs.is_valid():

            inp = Inputs.save(commit=False)
            inp.author = request.user
            inp.email = request.user.email

            data = {'email': request.user.email, **Inputs.cleaned_data}
            obtain_calculate_create_send(data)

            inp.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your form is valid!')
            return redirect('result/' + str(inp.pk) + '/')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'Please, check the inputs and enter valid ones')

        content = {'Inputs': Inputs, 'title': 'valuations'}

    else:
        Inputs = InputsForm(request.POST or None)
        content = {'Inputs': Inputs, 'title': 'valuations'}

    return render(request, 'valuations/form_home.html', content)
```

In forms.py:

```
class InputsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Basic Info 

    country_choices = import_lists('Countries', equal=True)
    years = import_lists('years')

    name = forms.CharField(label='Company Name', initial='Example. S.L')
    country = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=country_choices, label='Country')
    foundation_year = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=int, choices=years, label='Foundation year')
    employees = forms.IntegerField(label='Number of employees')
    industry = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=industry_choices, label='Industry')
    class Meta:
        model = Inputs
        exclude = ('author', 'email', 'date_inputs_created ')
```

and in the models.py:

```
class Inputs(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author}´s inputs for {self.name} created at {self.date_inputs_created}'

    # Useful information for the data base
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_inputs_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, default='example@compani.com')

    # Actual inputs
    # Basic Info 
    # ---------
    country_choices = import_lists('Countries', equal=True)
    industry_choices = import_lists('Industry', equal=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=country_choices, default='Germany')
    foundation_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=years)
    employees = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=20)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=industry_choices)
```

and in the HTML:

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ Inputs|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of how it can be changed, I think it can be achieved in three ways.

1. Using Django Signals to run a pre-save function that checks if the name contains 'S.L' and apply the field logics accordingly.
2. Changing your view function and apply logic there.
3. Hijack your Model save method and check if the name contains 'S.L' and apply the logic there.

I will go with Option 3 as it is simpler and faster. To give you an example, add below code in your **Inputs** model definition

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     name= self.name
     if name.endswith("S.L"):
         self.country = 'Company country'
         self.foundation_year = 'Company year'
    .... And so on ...........
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How the above code works is, for every incoming data, it checks if the name ends with 'S.L' and changes the logic.

You can change your view logic and apply this condition, but if you don't want to change the current view definition, this will do.

If you want to try option 2, then, try this out

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    Inputs = InputsForm(request.POST)

    if Inputs.is_valid():

        inp = Inputs.save(commit=False)
        inp.author = request.user
        inp.email = request.user.email

        # CODE -----------------------
        name = inp.name
        if name.endswith("S.L"):
           inp.country = 'Company country'
           inp.foundation_year = 'Company year'

          .... And so on ...........
        #CODE ! ----------------------             

        data = {'email': request.user.email, **Inputs.cleaned_data}
        obtain_calculate_create_send(data)

        inp.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Your form is valid!')
        return redirect('result/' + str(inp.pk) + '/')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, f'Please, check the inputs and enter valid ones')

    content = {'Inputs': Inputs, 'title': 'valuations'}

else:
    Inputs = InputsForm(request.POST or None)
    content = {'Inputs': Inputs, 'title': 'valuations'}

return render(request, 'valuations/form_home.html', content)
```

Comment: Hi, the thing is that this will just work if the form it's submitted but what I need it's that the fields that appear to the user change dynamically based on the inputs without submitting that inputs. So for example, you fill a field and then new fields appear without submitting and then you submit all the fields that had been filled and the rest appear to the database as null or default values.